# Recursive ctags for only one filetype

Tags: bash, recursion, ctags

I want to use ctags to create tags for a project, that is distributed over several subfolders.

I know that this can be done using `ctags -R *`.

Is it possible to restrict the generation to only use files with the same suffix? For example it should create tags for all `*.c` files but not for `*.h` files or Makefiles.

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I usually use

```
find -name '*.c' -exec ctags {} +
```

Answer (score 17):

If you use [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/) you can use `--languages` option. Example for parsing only php files is

```
ctags -R --languages=php
```

You can combine multiple languages using comma. To get a list of supported languages use `--list-languages` option.

Comment: Note, this also works for the older [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)